# How to select a method based on what's inside a string?

Tags: python

I'm using a package called sk-rf. The class provided has numerous methods. I built a wrapper around that class, and I want to use methods of that class based on string as follows:

```
my_string = "method1"

object.my_string()
```

I can do with with exec and eval, but I want something elegant, pro and not hacky.

Comment: Notice that object is an instance of class that I built on top of the class provided by that package.

Comment: Also, I don't want if statements cause there's a lot of methods

Comment: Does the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string help?

Comment: @user7761803 Hell yes. Many thanks.